# can't replace fragment within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I've got a ListFragment with this:

```
    public void fragmentSelection(Integer count) {
      Fragment fr;
      if (count == 0) {
        fr = new Fragment1();
      } else {
        fr = new Fragment2();
      }
      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fr, fr.getClass().getName());
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

here I am trying to replace the fragment content with fr (depends on count value)..

the part from XML looks like this

```
<fragment 
  android:id="@+id/content" 
  android:name="com.test.app.DefaultContent" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

Now when I want to replace fragment "content" with "fr" it do not replace it 1:1 - it adds fr down to the already current fragment (here `DefaultContent`) - so - why it does not replace it? What I have to do, that it replaces it and not puts the fr in addition below the current fragment

Comment: i replaced my <fragment> with FrameLayout - then it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The View ID you pass to `replace()`, in your case `R.id.content`, has to be the ID of the Fragment's parent View, not the original Fragment itself.

That means you have to set `android:id="@+id/content"` to the Fragment's parent, like this:

```
<FragmentLayout
    android:id="@+id/content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.test.app.DefaultContent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FragmentLayout>
```

Or, if that does not work for you, set a new ID to the parent and use it for `replace()`.

Comment: ohhhhhh okay, I will try... will give response in some minutes